# Data displaying from pages to tabhost

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-tabhost

Has anyone met this situation,right now i am trying to display the data from one screen to one of the tab in tabhost's which consists of two tabs.

Please find my code below

**mainclass.java**

```
 public class Demo_webserviceActivity extends Activity 
{

private static String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
   private static String METHOD_NAME = "FahrenheitToCelsius";
   private static String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/FahrenheitToCelsius";
   private static String URL = "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx?WSDL";

   Button btnFar;
   EditText txtFar;

       @Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
       {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.main);

       btnFar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnFar);

       txtFar = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);

       btnFar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
       {
       public void onClick(View v)
       {

           String b;

         //Initialize soap request + add parameters
         SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);       

         //Use this to add parameters
         request.addProperty("Fahrenheit",txtFar.getText().toString());

         //Declare the version of the SOAP request
         SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

         envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
         envelope.dotNet = true;

         try 
         {
             HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

             //this is the actual part that will call the webservice
             androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

             // Get the SoapResult from the envelope body.

             SoapPrimitive result = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();

             if(result != null)
             {
              //Get the first property and change the label text

                b = result.toString();

                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Tab_1.class);
                i.putExtra("gotonextpage", b.toString());
                startActivity(i);
              }

             else
             {
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "oops!.. empty",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
           e.printStackTrace();
               }
             }
           });
```

**Tab_1.java**

```
public class Tab_1 extends Activity 
{
TextView tv;
String result;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main2);

Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if(extras != null)
{
    result = extras.getString("gotonextpage");
}
tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.editText_tab1);
tv.setText(result);

}
}
```

can anyone tell me what mistake i am committing here?

Thanks for your Time!..